# rails_admin drag & drop top-level objects to sort

Tags: drag-and-drop, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I've got a "Store" (No db backed object) and there are items in the store. `StoreItem`.

An admin should be able to organize these objects. From what I've found on line, most rails_admin `orderable` assume that the objects are nested beneath another object through a `has_many`, but since there is only 1 store and no need to have an extra table, that's not the case.

Additionally, not all of the items appear in the store, so ideally I can have an additional tab on the index page like so:

```
Index | Add New | Export | Sort
```

Which can be used to show the relevant items and provider a drag & drop interface to organize these items.

What's going to be the cleanest way to allow an admin to accomplish this?

Comment: I'll go custom views and controllers, with rails admin at least, without one of the supported ORMs(Mongoid, ActiveRecord) you'll find your self hacking with no end.

Comment: @GuillermoSiliceoTrueba - I'm using Active Record - starting down the path of customizing the whole thing, just didn't want to reinvent the wheel. ‍♂️